# MSBuild for speficic changesets- more than one changeset !

Tags: msbuild, get, changeset

We are using MsBuild on TFS 2008 for building our solutions.

I need your advice and help about below scenario.

For example :

We prepared a full build for one of our customers.

After package is get ready, 2 developers want to add their development to the package.

I am trying to find a solution to add only the 2 developers code checkins to new build.

I mean i need to specify changeset numbers for MsBuild as parameter.

for example,  i only want to start a build for changeset number 200,400 and 434. 3 of them must be included the getting source process.

İ found a solution like /p:GetVersion:C1800

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/granth/archive/2008/06/26/how-to-make-team-build-get-a-previous-version.aspx

but this gets only one changeset. i need to specify more than one changeset number.

Or my approach can be totaly wrong, do you have any suggestions, guidance?

Thanks a lot,

Fatih.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If TFS Get command gets all the changesets up to your specified changeset. So if you want to include 200, 400 and 434, you only need to specify 434 as the changeset you want to get at. Note that this will also get all other changesets that are newer your workspace's version and older than 434.

I don't think TFS allows you to get **just** a specific changeset, unless you also specify the items you want to get. What I meant is, if changeset 123 includes files A, B, and C, and you just want to get this 123 changeset (and nothing else), you need to do something like

"tf get A;123"

"tf get B;123"

"tf get C;123"

You can find more information about the Get command [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fx7sdeyf%28v=VS.100%29.aspx).

**UPDATE:**

Just found out that the tfpt tool can get a specific changeset:

> Usage: tfpt getcs
>   /changeset:changesetnum [/force]
>   [/overwrite]
>
> Gets only the files in a particular
>   changeset at the version of the
>   changeset.
>
> /changeset             Specifies the
>   number of the changeset to get. 
>   /force                 Same as tf get
>   /force  /overwrite             Same as
>   tf get /overwrite

Comment: If you're using teambuild you can also pass command line input to MSbuild when you queue an new build [here is a blog explaining how](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/granth/archive/2008/06/26/how-to-make-team-build-get-a-previous-version.aspx)

Comment: I read the blog but the blog  says you can get only one changeset at a time. Is there any way to get more than once at a time?

Comment: Regarding your questions:

1) I don't think you can get just a set of specific changesets and exclude others in between. If you're OK with getting other changesets too, then do a get on the latest changeset will get ALL changes (200, 400 included) for your workspace.

2) TFS Build creates the workspace for you but you can define what the workspace mappings are. If your mappings include all the classes (A,B,C,D,E) then do a get on 434 will take care of getting 200 and 400. Of course you still need to get all changesets in between.